# Switch between 2 power sources

Tags: power, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, switching

I have one power source (bicycle dynamo) A.C 5-6V which will be rectified to D.C, and the other source D.C from a solar panel 12V. It will be 2 input source and one output.
what type of power switch would work best for this circuit? MOSFET BJT or any other? The output will be to a handheld device of 12V
Thanks for your time.

Comment: How will a 6 volt AC output become 12 volts dc with just a rectifier?

Comment: via transformer before rectified to 12V

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way of doing this is with two diodes, each one in series with each one of the voltage sources. The lower the forward voltage of the diodes, the better the solution. Since this is the case, the market also offers MOSFET based "active ORing diodes", like this one from TI

http://www.ti.com/product/lm5051

Comment: Two diodes can't help if the voltage of those two source voltages are very different.

Comment: @Uwe of course they will help since the idea is that one of the sources will be active, not both of them

Comment: one source will be stepped up to 12V via transformer, I should've have made it clearer, so both inputs will be 12v

Comment: @Claudio: It is possible that the bicycle dynamo and the solar panel are active both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Connect diode to each pin coming out from that dc supply and also do same with solar cell output wires but make sure that diodes are connected in forword bias means p to p and n to n  .now connect postive supply of solar cell to positive of dc supply n n negetive to negetive .                       [image]

Comment: @VishayShinde The additional diodes at the negatives are not needed. It is not only not needed but also it is not good since the losses are now twice what they would be if you connected the negative side together and used only diodes for the positive.

Comment: thanks, very helpful diagram. what type of diode?

Comment: You can use either simple diode or schottky diode

Comment: @claudio avi chami you can also connect that negetive supply directly I added them just for extra protection